# Why slice(0,-1) dont delete only one number on array

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice

I can't delete last number in string.I try .pop but if i have ["12","+","12"] he will pop 12 i need only one.

```
quene.slice(0,-1)
```

[image]
**I press CE but dont work**
[image]

Comment: `queue.pop()` will work ...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) In particular, please read [mcve]. We can't help you with the fragmentary information above. Separately: Include textual information **as text**, not as pictures of text.

Comment: *"I try .pop but if i have ["12","+","12"] he will pop 12 i need only one."* I'm afraid I can't make out what you're trying to say there.

Comment: Ok Sorry about bad question i will read that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder If i have in my array ["12","+","12"] how can i make to get  ["12","+","1"] i need to remove last character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the string length first and then do the rest based on that.

```
// check if last element length is more than 1
if(queue[queue.length - 1].length > 1){
  // remove last character and update string
  queue[queue.length - 1] = queue[queue.length - 1].slice(1, -1);
} else {
  // else remove the last element
  queue.pop();
}
```

or pop the last element, check the length of the string is greater than 1 then remove the last character and push to the array.

```
// pop last element from the array
let last = quene.pop();

// check if element length is more than 1
if(last.length > 1){
  // remove last character from string and push to the array again
  queue.push(last.slice(1, -1))
}
```

Comment: Don't know why dont work, i copied and paste to my code but they  remove every time last element. Maybe i can send u my code or what you want.I trying to debug in console but dont know why this dont work.

Comment: @TheLexa :  share your code in https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: There is site https://thelexa.000webhostapp.com/   code :https://jsfiddle.net/hd2879e1/6/

Comment: @TheLexa what's the expected behaviour?

Comment: When i click on 9,*,9 and press = he write me in textarea 9*9=81.In the display will be writed 81 when i press CE one character be remove  (81 》8 ) and press  *,8 and = in text area get *8=64 he removed 81 (in the qeune) i  need too remove only last character  .I need to get 8*8=64.If you dont understend i can make video.

Comment: @TheLexa you have to manage it in a different way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191348/discussion-between-pranav-c-balan-and-thelexa).